# NSFetchedResultsController performance with UITableView index

Tags: ios, performance, cocoa-touch, indexing, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm learning about `NSFetchedResultsController` and one thing puzzles me. The `NSFetchedResultsController` is used in combination with `UITableView` to help with fetching performance and to calculate which records to fetch based on what is currently shown in the `UITableView`.

When you use a `UITableView` index (like the first letters in the Addressbook app) doesn't that mean the whole dataset will be loaded to determine all the first letters of all the sections?

Doesn't the use of the index prevent the `NSFetchedResultsController` from being smart about what it loads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSFetchedResultsController` builds its index from the `sectionKeyPath`. One would assume that to get the values for this, a fetch would be performed to only get unique values for this key and not anything close to the full data set. For example, it could be doing something like making an `NSFetchRequest` with a result type of `NSDictionaryResultType`, `returnsDistinctResults` set to `YES`, and `propertiesToFetch` set only to `sectionKeyPath`.

Comment: Thx for answering my IOS newbie question. For reasons unknown I didn't think of this.